# Docker multi instances rethinkdb

Tags: docker, rethinkdb

i'd like to use rethinkdb with docker with many instances process  on the same pc

example

rethinkdb1
rethinkdb2
rethinkdb3
rethinkdb4

i was thinking to commit rethinkdb with different names like  rethinkdb2,3,4  but i doesn't seem to be the good solution

Thanks a lot for your advices

Jean-Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can add name on `docker container` easily

```
$ docker run --name [CUSTOM_NAME] IMAGE[:TAG]
```

For example `running rethinkdb`

```
$ docker run -d --name rethinkdb1 rethinkdb
9748b7f24ff3bc769054b5fd480ee31adfe47df1a2336353b807eb00a538620f
$ docker run -d --name rethinkdb2 rethinkdb
19364170a3d30b28fe36a83d7c90dd5e972446a03ba4d23a49a57c2fa16f7d57
$ docker run -d --name rethinkdb3 rethinkdb
1096d2b226f38d3f5313e6dfb639614898a4dc74da1f957c765376215c74625d
$ docker run -d --name rethinkdb4 rethinkdb
87aeee405999ff4838e0c1b447fa8d29650a70b75f315e7562ebc47a345c6033
```

Then you can check `docker ps`:

```
$ docker ps --format="table {{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}"
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               NAMES
87aeee405999        rethinkdb           rethinkdb4
1096d2b226f3        rethinkdb           rethinkdb3
19364170a3d3        rethinkdb           rethinkdb2
9748b7f24ff3        rethinkdb           rethinkdb1
```

Comment: so i have  4 processes but they are not reognised by rethinkdb like 4 servers

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you'd better use docker-compose with haproxy server

Comment: the following instruction rethinkdb --port-offset 1 --directory rethinkdb_data2 --join localhost:29015 should be used

Comment: how should look the dockerfile ?

Comment: rethinkdb1:
    image: "rethinkdb"  rethink2: image:"rethinkdb2"   rethink3:image:"rethinkdb3"